# Сравнение Строк Golang

Tags: golang

Напишите программу, которая проверяет правильность расчета на "раз два три".

Пользователь вводит последовательно 3 строки.

если эти строки "раз", "два", "три" - вывести "ОК" (кириллица)
если вместо строки "раз" введена "один" - вывести "ОК" (кириллица)
если вместо всех слов введены соответствующие числа "1", "2", "3" - вывести "ОК" (кириллица)
"НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО" - во всех остальных случаях

```
package main

import (

    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var A string
    fmt.Fscan(os.Stdin, &A)
    if &A == "раз, два, три " {
        fmt.Println("ОК")
    } else if &A == "один, два, три" {
        fmt.Println("ОК")
    } else if &A == "1 2 3" {
        fmt.Println("ОК")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО")
    }
}
}
```

Не пойму как сравнить строки

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так.  Условие в `correct` можно написать в одно
выражение, но мне так кажется понятнее:

```golang
func correct(lines []string) (ok bool) {
    if len(lines) != 3 {
        return false
    } else if (lines[0] == "один" || lines[0] == "раз") && (lines[1] == "два") && (lines[2] == "три") {
        return true
    } else if (lines[0] == "1") && (lines[1] == "2") && (lines[2] == "3") {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func main() {
    var err error

    var lines = make([]string, 0, 3)
    var s = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    for i := 0; s.Scan(); i++ {
        lines = append(lines, s.Text())
    }
    if err = s.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("scanning error: %s\n", err)
    }

    if !correct(lines) {
        log.Fatalln("НЕ ПРАВИЛЬНО")
    }

    log.Println("ОК")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать так еще, используя только один пакет - fmt.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main(){
    var val1, val2, val3 string
    fmt.Println("Пожалуйста, введите числа или слова ниже:")
    fmt.Scanln(&val1)
    fmt.Scanln(&val2)
    fmt.Scanln(&val3)

    if val1 == "Раз" && val2 == "Два" && val3 == "Три" {
        fmt.Println("ОК")
    } else if val1 == "Один" {
        fmt.Println("ОК")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("НЕПРАВИЛЬНО!")
    }
}
```